# How to update/refresh kendo multiselect template?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

i have a kendo multiselect which is using a tagTemplate so that when you select options it displays `x of y selected`. My problem is, when an item is added to the datasource i need to update parameter `y` but i don't know how to refresh the template. Here's my html template and my js code:

HTML Template:

```
<script id="SelectedViewsTagTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    #:values.length# #='@Html.Raw(rm.GetString("STR_OF"))# #:total-1#
</script>
```

Javascript for tagtemplate:

```
            tagTemplate: function (dataItem) {
                dataItem.total = _getTotal.call(this);
                dataItem.total += dataItem.AddMode ? 1 : 0;
                return kendo.template($("#SelectedViewsTagTemplate").html())(dataItem);
            }
```

I've tried triggering the "change" event to get it to update but it doesn't seem to work, aside from recreating the multiselect i don't know how to refresh the template

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this problem I ended up finding a work-around to refreshing the multiSelect template.. recreate the object containing the elements that you use in your template in js, and call the template function like this:

```
var templateObject = {
   values: currentMultiSelect.value(),
   total: currentMultiSelect.value().length
};
currentMultiSelect.options.tagTemplate(templateObject);
```

since i only use `total` and `values` in my template those are the only properties i need in my object